# Adobe Flex Mobile Error 1144: Interface method initialize in namespace mx.core:IUIComponent is implemented with an incompatible signature

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, mobile, air

Forgive me if I am missing something here, I'm a bit new to Flex Mobile development.

Can someone tell me what this error means? I was just working on this project, and now it won't compile. I tried undoing the changes I just did, no dice.

```
1144: Interface method initialize in namespace mx.core:IUIComponent is implemented with an incompatible signature in class MyApp.
myApp.mxml  /MyApp/src  Unknown Flex Problem
```

Comment: Sometimes errors like this are a result of using a library compiled w/ an earlier version of the Flex SDK than your main project.  So, if you're using any SWCs; make sure they are compiled with the same version of Flex as your main project.

Comment: They are, that's what stumped me. But anyway, I managed to clear it. Posting an answer now, in case anyone else happens to get this. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Flash Builder, and after several Project Cleans and Rebuilds, I finally got the error to clear.

Eventually, I cleared the MyApp.mxml file, did a clean and build, changed it to the following:

```
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

then did a clean/build again, then re-pasted the actual contents, and the error magically went away.

So I have no clue what actually caused the error, or how I even fixed it, but I've seen Visual Studio do similar quirky things as a .NET developer.

Oh well. Its working now, so I'm not going to complain.